# Setting a group margin in a Windows 8.1 GridView

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm using a WinRT GridView, displaying grouped data. I have a design requirement to specify a 20px gap between each of the groups of items in the grid.

I notice that when I use an ItemsWrapGrid for the ItemsPanelTemplate, that I can set the GroupPadding property, but there is no GroupMargin property.

I have tried substituting the ItemsWrapGrid with a StackPanel, which allows me to Set the GroupStyle.Panel (where I can specify a VariableSizedWrapGrid and set a group margin). This meets the requirements of my visual design perfectly, but unfortunately there are negative performance consequences of using a StackPanel, since that will not allow the GridView to use Virtualization.

I have also tried substituting the ItemsWrapGrid with a ItemsStackPanel (which does support virtualization) but this gives weird horizontal scrollbar behaviour when scrolling through groups with varying amounts of items. (The scroll bar gets bigger and smaller).

Here is a code snippet of what I have so far:

```
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid  Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                Background="Red" 
                                GroupPadding="0,0,80,0">
                </ItemsWrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

The Margin property applies to the entire Grid. The GroupPadding property correctly sets a gap between the groups, but I need to set a Background color for each group (Red in this example) with a transparent gap between each group.

**tl;dr:**
I want a GridView with grouped data with a ItemsWrapGrid as the ItemsPanel that I can set a Group Margin on.

Answer (score 4):

I'd also **love to know how** to do this **properly** I've been messing around with trying to get a **margin effect between my groups** now for far too long. N.B. this is a Win 8.1 Store app

I resorted to the following (very ugly, hacky) solution, which I'm not happy with.

**My Specific Requirements**

1. Margin / Border of 25px lighter shade of background separating each group in a grouped GridView (happens to be inside SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView)
2. Header for each group is horizontal and spans whole width of group
3. Items withing the group displayed in a GridView fashion, i.e. stacked vertically in rows until the columns is filled, then spilling over into a new column

**Hacky Nasty Ugly Solution**

- Need ItemsWrapGrid to ensure "flow" of items within the group is correct
- Added GroupPadding to give me the gap needed between each group
- Used an ImageBrush as the background - which is a very very wide image with the lighter shade as a vertical bar every X pixels (x=width of group)

If anyone had **a better solution** would be **much appreciated** as this currently makes me feel a little ill and reminds me of nasty nasty 1px spacer images on the web ;(

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid Background="{StaticResource ImgBack}"
            GroupHeaderPlacement="Top"
            GroupPadding="25,0,0,0">
        </ItemsWrapGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>

...

<ImageBrush x:Key="ImgBack" ImageSource="/Assets/GridBackRepeat.png"
    AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None" AlignmentY="Top">
</ImageBrush>
```

**Note**

I tried to use styles (TargetType="GroupItem" containing ContentControl x:Name="HeaderContent" and ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl") to try and layout the group header vs group items in something other than the default 2 row grid, which worked fine... Except for the *infuriating fact* that it only worked when I used something other than ItemsWrapGrid, i.e. StackPanel, which breaks my requirement 3.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [GroupStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.groupstyle) class. It allows you to set a style for each group, including separate templates for the header and group itself. The example style given in that page is:

```
<GridView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="LightGray" Margin="0">
                    <TextBlock Text='{Binding Name}' 
                               Foreground="Black" Margin="30"
                               Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="600"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0"/>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>

        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
    </GroupStyle>
</GridView.GroupStyle>
```

Notice the `ContainerStyle` property, where you can set a `Margin`. You can also set the Panel for each item there.

The ItemsPanel you were applying to your GridView was being applied across the entire list (as you noticed). A grouped GridView is a list of lists, so you need to apply the change to each individual group. The GroupStyle is how you do that.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Edit: What I have personally done in my app is to change the Margin on the `GroupStyle.Panel`.

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
```

Comment: Hi Nate, Thanks for trying, but as indicated in my question, I've already tried specifying the GroupStyle settings, but this only works when the GridView.ItemsPanel is not an ItemsWrapGrid. Unfortunately, the GroupStyle.ContainerStyle Property is deprecated and actually ignored in 8.1 when using the default ItemsWrapGrid as the GridView ItemsPanel.

Comment: Added a clarification. I add a margin to the GroupStyle's Panel, which works.

Comment: Thanks again, but as I mentioned, your solution will only work in Win 8.1 when your GridView.ItemsPanel is not an ItemsWrapGrid. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx for details.
It may well be working for you, but you won't be using a ItemsWrapGrid, which we need for performance reasons.

Comment: Can you add the padding/coloring in your `ItemTemplate` or `ItemContainerStyle`?

Comment: I did try padding/coloring to the ItemContainerStyle, but had some trouble getting a consistent spacing between the items, plus my group background has some transparency, which stacks badly if I try to apply negative margins. This didn't help me, but it might help someone else, so I'll +1 it. Thanks.

Comment: @Nate +1 for attempt, thanks, but I basically have same issue / requirements as Scott, and so resorted to horrible hack below. ;(